# Prestashop 1.6.1.9 Instant search

Tags: prestashop-1.6

Hi I have a problem with the top search box and I don't know how to debug it, 
the search function used to show product instantly when the user writes the search term, but now it shows empty page till the user hits enter.

you can check it here:
www.elektrojo.com

- Instant search is enabled
- I tried to reset the module but didn't work.
- I also tried to remove the previous modules I installed and no luck

[EDIT]
for some reason the instant search file  was not included in the theme files, but now if the user wrote something the results will appear and if he decided to cancel the search the page does not go back to normal, instead an empty page shows

Thanks

Comment: Your website isn't working

Answer (score 0):

Go into your back office, select `Preferences->Search`.
You should see a section called Indexation
click `Re-build entire index`.

This might fix your problem.

Check below link of forums also.

[LINK 1](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/34129-solved-search-is-not-working/)

[LINK 2](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/212614-prestashop-1473-search-suddenly-not-working-within-last-few-days/)

Answer (score 0):

(PrestaShop version 1.6.0.14) My search box was not working. After searching for answers, just about every article, video, forum I looked at, had the same fix. But they wasn't working for me.
I actually tripped over my problem. This probably won't work for all but check this:
bring up one of your products,@ this point doesn't matter which one, on the "information"
tab, look at the "Visibility" window. make sure "everywhere" is selected. then save.
Mine, I have catalog selected on all but 2 products.
My search box is working now!! 
I feel so dumb!
I really hope this help someone else.I know how frustrating something can be.